# Internationalized Phonenumber regex

Tags: javascript, regex

i wrote the following regular expression to determine if a national or international telephone number has the right pattern.

/^(00|0|[+])([-][0-9]|[0-9]){1,13}[0-9]/

The Pattern could be improved by splitting the numbers into countrycode and phone number but this does not matter yet.

Thanks for your help

edit: here´s the code. It should not be the problem because other regex work well. oChanged is a textinput.

```
    function verification(oChanged, regex){
   var val = $(oChanged).val();
   var reg = new RegExp(regex);
   if( !reg.test(val) ){
       if( !$(oChanged).hasClass('notvalid') ){
            $(oChanged).addClass('notvalid');
       }

   }else{
       if( $(oChanged).hasClass('notvalid') ){
            $(oChanged).removeClass('notvalid');
       }
   }
}
```

I tested it with some regex testers in the internet and it matched all these strings but when I implement it it does not match.

it should work for e.g. 004915773554660 +4915773554660  015773554660  0049157-7355-466-0

Comment: Post your implementation here.

Comment: Show the code which doesn't work - just the regex may not be enough. Also consider using a specialized library like [libphonenumber](https://catamphetamine.github.io/libphonenumber-js/) instead of a regex

Comment: In `[+]` seems the `[ ]` are redundant. It fails with international format numbers in the format +ccAnnnnnnnn where cc is a 2 digit country code, A an area code and n… an 8 digit landline or mobile number. How is "national" determined?

Comment: @kristaps the code works well for other regexes (hope it´s the right plural).

Comment: And @RobG national would we be number without countrycode introduced by 0 like: 015773554660 or 030333555. Your´re right i also thought the Brackets would be Reundand but without them i ru into an "unexpected quantifier" error message. I think it is the combination with `^` and `()`. Maybe i should append: I always test this stuff in the internet explorer. I´m meant to....

Comment: Because `+` on its own is a quantifier (one or more), but within `[ ]` it's a literal "+", so outside the brackets use `\+` to make it a literal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Please use this one:**

/(+\d{1,3}\s?)?(((\d{3})\s?)|(\d{3})(\s|-?))(\d{3}(\s|-?))(\d{4})(\s?(([E|e]xt[:|.|]?)|x|X)(\s?\d+))?/g

Demo: https://www.regextester.com/103299

**Full number**

+999 (999) 999-9999 Ext. 99999

**Regular local phone number (XXX) XXX-XXXX**

1231231231
123-1231231
123123-1231
123-123 1231
123 123-1231
123-123-1231
(123)123-1231
(123)123 1231
(123) 123-1231
(123) 123 1231

**International codes +XXX (XXX) XXX-XXXX**

+99 1234567890
+991234567890

**Extensions (XXX) XXX-XXXX Ext. XXX...**

1234567890 Ext 1123123
1234567890Ext 1123123
1234567890 Ext1123123
1234567890Ext1123123

Comment: thanks for that. i will test it. But i still want to know why my own regex don´t work. In my understanding of the Pattern it should be right and it drives me crazy not to know why it´s not working.

Comment: Where I live, no one formats their phone numbers like +999 (999) 999-9999. Local numbers in an international context are +99 9 9999 9999 and national they're 09 9999 9999. The "+" indicates the international access code and is typically "00", or "001", the country code can be 1, 2 or 3 digits (USA 1, UK 44, Albania 355), area codes might also be 1, 2 or 3 digits. I seriously doubt that one regular expression can do it all with any sort of rigour.

Comment: sorry to say it but your regex also don´t work for me. `Error: unexpected quantifier`. When i escape it like `\+` it also shows the error. When I try `[\+]` it does not but every "valid" number like +4915773554660 or 004915773554660 or 015773554660 does not match.